# rounding values in R

Tags: r, rounding

I am trying to quickly round numbers from a normal distribution to a whole number between 1 and 10.
I want to pull a random number from a distribution, but then round to a whole number between 1 and 10.
If I run:
rnorm(1, 10, 2.5)
I get something like 12.5689 which is greater than 10. I know I can use round or ceiling to round these values, but I am unsure how get it down to 10 without creating a function that has to sift thru each data point for each iteration and correct them. I have the same problem on the lower bound with 1 and finding values that are either negative or less than 1.
thanks!

Comment: Do you realize that your mean is 10? This will likely lead to roughly half of your values being above your cutoff. This won't really be a normal distribution in the end, and you really shouldn't be getting negative values very often with a mean of 10 and a sd of 2.5.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain it clearly enough in the original post - I am running this with a mean of 10 and a mean of 1. When I run it with mean 1 it results in some negative values being produced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pmin` and `pmax` are your friends:

```
pmin(10, pmax(1, round(rnorm(10, 10, 2.5))))
#  [1]  9  8  9  8 10 10 10  9 10 10
```

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a ton of time